# Persisted String List property RealmSwift

Tags: swift, realm, realm-list

I am trying to set an array of String to a List of String for my Realm Object, but I got and error "Generic type 'List' specialized with too few type parameters (got 1, but expected 2)".

I tried `List<NSString>`, `List<String>`, `List<String>()`, I also tried to create my own Object with a value, and I even tried the documentation code and it has the same issue

I tried to put another argument to see which kind of second argument he was waiting for but the error goes to "Generic type 'List' specialized with too many type parameters (got 2, but expected 1)" that sounds to be a legit error

```swift
import RealmSwift
import SwiftUI

// Define your models like regular Swift classes
class Dog: Object {
    @Persisted var name: String
    @Persisted var age: Int
}
class Person: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: String
    @Persisted var name: String
    @Persisted var age: Int
    // Create relationships by pointing an Object field to another Class
    @Persisted var dogs: List<Dog> // Error here
}
```

Comment: I import SwiftUI and RealmSwift only

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks it is conflicts with SwiftUI List I didn't thought about that, I needed SwiftUI to generate UUID for my Object, what's should I use instead ? ObjectIdentifier ?

Comment: @Sweeper Sure let me do that quickly

Comment: @Sweeper I also added my imports to be more clear about the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are importing SwiftUI, the compiler is thinking that you meant the [SwiftUI `List`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list) type, which indeed, has 2 type arguments.

You can refer to the Realm `List` type by qualifying it:

```
@Persisted var dogs: RealmSwift.List<Dog>
@Persisted var someStrings: RealmSwift.List<String>
```

Or better, don't put your data in the same file as your UI. You should separate them!

Comment: I did imported SwiftUI only for UUID, at first it was for more, but I refactored and I forgot that UUID and that import, don't worry I do not mix Models and UI.
To correct the issue I prefer removing SwiftUI that is completely useless to import there. Thank you for the help

Comment: @SnK For UUID, you can just import `Foundation`.

Answer (score 0):

It was due to conflicts with SwiftUI import, List, prefer using Foundation for UUID, or use RealmSwift integrated ObjectId